# Learn Python the hard way ex25 no module named ex25

Tags: python

I'm lost with this I saw several answers to similar problems, but no success in my case

```
     Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Majul> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on wi
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> execfile("c:\python27\scripts\ex25.py")
import ex25
>>> sentence = "all good things come to those who wait."
>>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ex25' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Do you have a module `ex25.py`?

Comment: You should've posted the example as well. You cannot just assume that people will know the example and will be able to help you. Plus it's very likely that you don't have the file `ex25.py`.

Answer (score 0):

from looking at what you have provided you have typed in "execfile("c:\python27\scripts\ex25.py")" in which the instructions in the lesson do not say to do that. According to the lesson you must must make the file then open up the python interpreter and type in exactly what zed says. If you haven't make any syntax errors in your ex25.py code then it should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The import is case sensitive, make sure that you have not capitalised the file name, i.e. it is not saves as Ex25.py

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue.
Fixed it by adding PYTHONPATH to env. Variables and setting the path to my work folder `C:\users\%User%\Desktop` in most cases I suppose? Anyways hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
execfile("/path/to/py/file")
```

and then use functions in that module.
Hope that helps

**Edit:**

After including the .py file, there is no need to use

```
words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
```

You have to use the function directly, this way

```
words = break_words(sentence)
```

That is, looking at the example you posted.

Comment: How is this related to the question?